Airflow DAG that runs a Windows process
I would like to set up an automation pipeline that involves programmatically using a Windows application. Unfortunately, there is no way around using the Windows application as there are no other endpoints available other than through Windows COM.
I can use pywin32 to do what I need with the Windows application. However, I would like to find a way to run this inside an Airflow DAG.
The typical suggested methods of installing Airflow on Windows involve either WSL or a Docker container that runs an Ubuntu-like image. However, this means that Airflow would not be installed in the same environment as where I have pywin32.
Is there a way I can get Airflow installed via WSL to trigger a Python script running on the host Windows environment?
